# powerline network adapters between main transmission line

Tags: routing, ieee-802.11

I have a situation where my outhouse is bit far from the home.And both have two electricity connections.Will it be possible to use a powerline adapter between the main transmission lines to share the Internet ?
What will be the loss if I do so?
I am from India where the voltage is 240 V and frequency is 50hz.

Comment: Home networking is off topic for this forum. See the Help Center for allowed/disallowed types of questions.

Comment: Forget about home networking ,but please answer with respect to power line adapters

Comment: Powerline adapters are consumer networking products. You can try on Super User.